# HttpWebRequest Won't Serialize

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, serialization

I'm getting the following error when I try to Serialize an HttpWebRequest

> Type 'System.Net.KnownHttpVerb' in
>   Assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is
>   not marked as serializable.

Using .Net Framework 2.0

This is one of the properties that my class holds. It's a requirement to serialize it.

HttpWebRequest is marked as Serializable so it supposed to Serialize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if one of the contained objects is marked as non-serializable, I believe you're "out of luck" using the default serializer.

If possible, I would recommend instead taking the parameters used to instantiate your web request and serializing those instead.
Write a custom serializer/deserializer to reconstitute the uncooperative object.

EDIT: There's a fairly good article on it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163902.aspx).

EDIT2: In fact, after a little googling, it appears that this is your only option, as the Serializable attribute on HttpWebRequest has been marked obsolete as of .net 2.0. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497288.aspx#System.Net) for details (search for HttpWebRequest).

Comment: HttpWebRequest is marked as Serializable so it supposed to Serialize

Comment: Well, the HttpWebRequest class apparently contains a System.Net.KnownHttpVerb which is *not* serializable. That's what is causing the problem.

And I'll edit SOL to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't see why MS made it obsolete, It's my seriliazer and I was happy with the size overhead, it's so much easier than writing more code :)

Anyway thanks for the answers and Thanks to MS!

Comment: It makes sense because most of the instance represent temporal artifacts like the underlying socket and related transmit/receive buffers.  These cannot be de/rehydrated.  The bug was marking it as serializable in the 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.HttpWebRequest serialization was marked as obselete in .NET 2.0.

Official documents here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa497288.aspx

From an app perspective this is the best outcome.  The predominant bulk of an HttpWebRequest instance is IO state that is typically not directly rehydratable.

As @Andrew-Rollings suggests instead implement a custom serialize to store/restore your request parameters, then recreate the HttpWebRequest instance from scratch.