# How to request an aborted HttpWebRequest again?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

My objective is to retry an asynchronous HttpWebRequest when it fails.

When I [Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.abort.aspx) an HttpWebRequest, I cannot BeginGetResponse() again. So the only way to request again probably is recreate the HttpWebRequest object. It seems to require a lot of work since I would have to copy all properties from the old object. Is there any shortcut?

Note: I think that serialization it would solve my problem, but this class won't serialize, as discussed in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351265/httpwebrequest-wont-serialize).

**Update** Removed example source code because it was unnecessary

**Current view on this matter** There is no shortcut, the only way to redo the request is creating another HttpWebRequest object the same way you created the original one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### It's possible!

You just need to create a new `HttpWebRequest` and copy all of the properties over to it from the old object via reflection.

Here's an **extension method** that does this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Clones a HttpWebRequest for retrying a failed HTTP request.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="original"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static HttpWebRequest Clone(this HttpWebRequest original)
{
    // Create a new web request object
    HttpWebRequest clone = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(original.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);

    // Get original fields
    PropertyInfo[] properties = original.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // There are some properties that we can't set manually for the new object, for various reasons
    List<string> excludedProperties = new List<String>(){ "ContentLength", "Headers" };

    // Traverse properties in HttpWebRequest class
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        // Make sure it's not an excluded property
        if (!excludedProperties.Contains(property.Name))
        {
            // Get original field value
            object value = property.GetValue(original);

            // Copy the value to the new cloned object
            if (property.CanWrite)
            {
                property.SetValue(clone, value);
            }
        }
    }

    return clone;
}
```

When you want to re-issue the same request, simply execute the following:

```
// Create a request
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/");

// Change some properties...

// Execute it
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

// Clone the request to reissue it using our extension method
request = request.Clone();

// Execute it again
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.

Comment: Great idea!  But, I'm not sure which Headers you would _not_ want to copy.  If you have authorization info, for example, you will need to copy the Headers (at least some of them) for the next attempt to succeed.

Comment: The extension method doesn't copy the headers as C# throws an exception when trying to write the entire headers to that property. You would need to tweak the code to read each individual header as a Key, Value pair and write it into the new cloned object, one header at a time.

Answer (score 14):

It's not possible.

An HTTPWebRequest instance represents literally one request instance (although there are edge cases where it will retry internally), and is therefore not something which can logically be repeated. It is capable of returning exactly one response (request/response being a logical pair), and although you can inspect that response multiple times you'll get exactly the same object.

Basically, you're thinking an HTTPWebRequest instance is a sort of factory, but it's really concrete. You have to create another instance.

Comment: There is a way, check out my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you trying to serialize the request?  It might be a good idea to serialize the request *before* you try to make it, and then resend the request on failure (from the serialized instance).

Also, you might want to remove the proxy, serialize the instance, and then set the proxy back, since that seems to be where the problem lies in serializing the request.

Comment: The full code doesn't contains the serialization because it didn't work, but if I include the serialization in the code I would certainly do as you told. The piece of code I wrote for serialization tests doesn't have any line about proxies, and I don't know how to remove it. Do you?

Comment: removed the serialization sample code and replaced it with a link to another SO Question about serializing HttpWebRequest (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351265/httpwebrequest-wont-serialize)

Answer (score 2):

There is no shortcut, the only way to redo the request is creating another HttpWebRequest object the same way you created the original one.