# Unable to Serialize HttpWebRequest (Type 'System.Net.WebRequest+WebProxyWrapper' is not marked as serializable.)

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.0

In order to log some HTTP traffic I'm trying to serialize an instance of System.Net.HttpWebRequest.  The application uses MVC 3 and the problem code is in an action method in a controller class.

In .NET Framework 4 it the class is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) as serializable:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
  public class HttpWebRequest : WebRequest, 
      ISerializable
```

The following test code fails at the indicated statement:

```
...
HttpWebRequest preapprovalRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://big.URL.here");
...
HttpWebResponse preapprovalResponse = (HttpWebResponse)preapprovalRequest.GetResponse();


// Serialize the request context.
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream msRequest = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(msRequest, preapprovalRequest); //<<<<< Error here.
// Reset the stream and deserialize.
msRequest.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
HttpWebRequest duplicateRequest = (HttpWebRequest)formatter.Deserialize(msRequest);
msRequest.Close();

// Serialize the response context.
MemoryStream msResponse = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(msResponse, preapprovalResponse);
// Reset the stream and deserialize.
msResponse.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
HttpWebResponse duplicateResponse = (HttpWebResponse)formatter.Deserialize(msResponse);
msResponse.Close();
```

The error reported is:

```
Type 'System.Net.WebRequest+WebProxyWrapper' in Assembly
'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
is not marked as serializable.
```

I've tried chasing WebProxyWrapper with no joy.  Just a bit of unhelpful baggage.  Explicitly casting the HttpWebRequest to a WebRequest doesn't alter the error:

```
formatter.Serialize(msRequest, (WebRequest)preapprovalRequest);
```

On the bright side, the code does properly serialize and deserialize the instance of HttpWebResponse.

How can I lose the wrapper?  Is there a better approach?

Comment: The answer is *you cannot serialize HttpWebRequest and you shouldn't be doing that.*  The **real** question involves *why* you are trying to do this.

Comment: It didn't seem unreasonable to log my request and PayPal's response when an error occurs or something unexpected, e.g. a new name/value pair, comes back in the response.  It also didn't seem unreasonable to attempt to serialize something documented as having [SerializableAttribute].  Are you suggesting, perhaps, that Microsoft might have erred in their documentation?

Comment: But you aren't serializing that class, as you have found.  You are serializing something else.  It is possible to get the bytes from the request and save *those*, which would be essentially what you wish to do without the overhead of serializing a request/response object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpWebRequest Won't Serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351265/httpwebrequest-wont-serialize)

Comment: @Cœur The accepted answer to the proposed duplicate question leads to "Serialization is obsoleted for this type." That question includes "Using .Net Framework 2.0". _This_ question is specific to ".NET Framework 4" and includes a link to the version 4 documentation which showed the `[SerializableAttribute]` had been restored. The answer, provided by Microsoft, was that the New & Improved documentation was wrong.

Comment: @HABO close vote retracted: note that old links to a wrong duplicate need to be manually removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official answer from Microsoft:

> Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately HttpWebRequest dropped
>   support for serialization after .NET 1.1. See
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.httpwebrequest(v=VS.100).aspx
>
> We’ll see if we can get that attribute removed to avoid this confusion
>   in the future.

They changed the documentation to include the [ObsoleteAttribute] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
[Serializable()]
public class MyClass
{
    //your serializable class
}
```

Comment: The problem instance is a variable in a method, not a property of another class.  (HttpWebRequest preapprovalRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://horrific.URL.here");
)  The method is an action in an MVC controller.  Trying [Serializable] on the controller class doesn't alter the outcome.  Nor do I expect it to actually be serializable.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the wrapper was not marked as serializable. Can you provide a little more context?

Comment: To narrow the universe of discourse I moved the test code to a minimal console application.  The error is unchanged, which leads me to believe that it is unlikely to be a problem with one of my classes.  By way of context: The code builds an HTTP request which is sent to PayPal where, if it is not found wanting, a response is generated and returned.  Since PayPal sometimes does unpredicatable things I'd like to be able to log some of the exhcnages.  That's about it.